# How to automount external USB disks when system wakes up?

Tags: usb, suspend, automount

I have a Thinkpad running 21.10 connected to a Thinkpad dock that has external USB disk drives connected to it. When I'm done using the laptop, I unmount the disks, disconnect the dock and let the laptop go to sleep on its own. The next morning, I reconnect the dock and tap the power button on the laptop to wake it up.

I'm pretty sure than in a previous 2x.xx release of Ubuntu, the disks would automount when the laptop wakes up and I unlock the screen with my password. Under 21.10, they don't automount.

Is there a way to configure the system to automatically mount the disks?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: *I'm pretty sure than in a previous 2x.xx release of Ubuntu, the disks would automount* I'm pretty sure that wasn't the case if you were doing what you described.

Comment: By unmounting the disks and letting the notebook sleep, you are explicitly telling the machine not to use the devices. A boot every morning would remount the disks, but simply waking from sleep will not 

Comment: I'm not sure of the best way to handle this, since the USB disks are connected through the dock. The laptop is always closed and connected to an external monitor. It is charged through the dock. Is it better to leave the disks mounted, leave the dock connected, and leave the laptop closed, and simply turn off the power to the dock?